# How do you declare a function with definition func(cv::Mat &img) in C++

Tags: c++, function-declaration

How do you declare a function defined as such:

```
void func(cv::Mat &img)
{
    ...
}
```

**More details:**

I defined the function "func" in my main.cpp file below the "main" function. The compiler complained that it didn't know what the function "func" was, so I tried to put the prototype above the "main" function.

I tried

```
void func(cv::Mat);
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Why would you not declare it as `void func(cv::Mat &img);`?

Comment: `void func(cv::Mat &img)` it's not a definition, it's a signature.

Comment: name of parameter is not important in declaration, but the '&' is a part of type (`void func(cv::Mat &img)` is the same as `void func(cv::Mat& img)` . so you can use `void func(cv::Mat &);`

Comment: I tried `void func(cv::Mat&);` but it didn't work. I was close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Declare*?

Just

```
void func(cv::Mat &img);
```

and that's it. Or even just

```
void func(cv::Mat &);
```

since parameter names in non-defining declarations serve no purpose (aside from making the code more readable).

However, for most entities in C++ (and C) a *definition* is just a specific kind of *declaration* (i.e. the term "definition" can be thought of as just a shorthand for "defining declaration"). By *defining* this function you also *declared* it (for the code that follows the definition).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could actually put parameter names into declarations. I always though you could only put types. I used `void func(cv::Mat &)` and that worked!